# Adding a image to a d3 node along with circle

Tags: d3.js

I did google could not find what i am looking for.

I wanted to add a image toa d3 node, but not by replacing the whole node. but along with the d3 circle node i want the image also appended. something like adding a label to the node.

I want this to mark a node. for example in a topology, wanted to show the source and destination of a path.

**Edited:**
if there is better way to do this also please suggest.
i tried adding the image to the node. i could see the image is added in the firebug, but it is not visible.

Tried in the fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/pkolanda/2ryu34qv/

```
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    nodeEnter
      .append("img")
      .attr("src","https://lh4.ggpht.com/Tr5sntMif9qOPrKV_UVl7K8A_V3xQDgA7Sw_qweLUFlg76d_vGFA7q1xIKZ6IcmeGqg=w300");
```

In the fiddle i am trying to add to all the nodes. based on the user event i will select a node to mark.

Comment: I am getting a 404 when attempting to view the fiddle. Can you repost the link?

Comment: Sorry.. it was midnight... so made a mistake :( updated now

Answer (score 1):

The jsfiddle page is 404 right now, try below code:

```
  var pattern_def = svg.append("defs");  //append defs in svg
  nodeEnter = svg.selectAll(".some-node")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class","some-node")
                .attr({
                    "cx": 50,
                    "cy": 50,
                    "r": 10
                })
                .each(function(d,i){
                    // append image pattern for each node
                    pattern_def.append("pattern")
                        .attr("id", "node-img")
                        .attr("patternUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
                        .attr({
                            "width": "100%",
                            "height": "100%"
                        })
                        .attr({
                            "viewBox": "0 0 1 1" 
                        })
                        .append("image")
                        .attr("xlink:href", d.imageUrl) //use xlink:href with image url 
                        .attr({
                            "x":0,
                            "y":0,
                            "width": "1",
                            "height": "1",
                            "preserveAspectRatio": "none"
                        })

                    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "url(#node-img)") 
                   // fill node with the image pattern
                   // if the image is fixed for every node, you can add the fill attribute in node settings
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2ryu34qv/2/)

```
nodeEnter
    .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.img; })
  .attr("x", "-12px")
  .attr("y", "-44px")
  .attr("width", "24px")
  .attr("height", "24px");
```